# EF Core 3.0 Select Projection with index overload (aka .Select((entity, index) => new {}) fails

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have current setup, with a Select indexer-projection (entity, index) (see SubRubrics). If i leave the indexer out, the problem is solved... However if I leave out the SubRubricItems then I can use the indexer. Is it only on the last select projection I can use it, or..?

Below linq projection, error message and more info.

```
await _db
                        .Exams
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Include(exam => exam.Stations)
                        .ThenInclude(station => station.Rubrics)
                        .ThenInclude(rubric => rubric.SubRubrics)
                        .ThenInclude(subRubric => subRubric.Items)
                        .Select(exam => new Result.ExamViewModel
                        {
                            Id = exam.Id,
                            Name = exam.Name,
                            Stations = exam.Stations.Select(station => new Result.StationViewModel
                            {
                                Id = station.Id,
                                Description = station.Description,
                                Rubrics = station.Rubrics.Select(rubric => new Result.RubricViewModel
                                {
                                    Id = rubric.Id,
                                    Name = rubric.Name,
                                    Info = rubric.Info,
                                    SubRubrics = rubric.SubRubrics.Select((subRubric, index) => new Result.SubRubricViewModel
                                    {
                                        Id = subRubric.Id,
                                        Order = index,
                                        Name = subRubric.Name,
                                        Info = subRubric.Info,
                                        Type = subRubric.Type.ToString(),
                                        Items = subRubric.Items.Select(item => new Result.SubRubricItemViewModel
                                        {
                                            Id = item.Id,
                                            Name = item.Name
                                        })
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                        .ToListAsync()
```

This provides this error which I don't understand :/

```
InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression '(MaterializeCollectionNavigation(
    navigation: Navigation: Rubric.SubRubrics,
    subquery: (NavigationExpansionExpression
        Source: DbSet<SubRubric>
            .Where(s0 => !(s0.IsDeleted))
            .Where(s0 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(r, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(r, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(s0, "RubricId"))
        PendingSelector: s0 => (NavigationTreeExpression
            Value: (EntityReference: SubRubric | IncludePaths: Items)
            Expression: s0)
    )
        .Where(i => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>((NavigationTreeExpression
            Value: (EntityReference: Rubric | IncludePaths: Version SubRubrics->...)
            Expression: r), "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<long>>((NavigationTreeExpression
            Value: (EntityReference: Rubric | IncludePaths: Version SubRubrics->...)
            Expression: r), "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(i, "RubricId")))
    .AsQueryable()
    .Select((subRubric, index) => new SubRubricViewModel{ 
        Id = subRubric.Id, 
        Order = index, 
        Name = subRubric.Name, 
        Info = subRubric.Info, 
        Type = subRubric.Type.ToString(), 
        Items = subRubric.Items
            .AsQueryable()
            .Select(item => new SubRubricItemViewModel{ 
                Id = item.Id, 
                Name = item.Name 
            }
            ) 
    }
    )' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
```

This used to work, until I added the extra `SubRubricItems` select for the Items model, aka

```
Items = subRubric.Items.Select(item => new Result.SubRubricItemViewModel
                                        {
                                            Id = item.Id,
                                            Name = item.Name
                                        })
```

For reference sake, this is the viewmodel that's being projected into:

```
public sealed class Result
        {
            public IEnumerable<ExamViewModel> Exams { get; set; }

            public sealed class ExamViewModel
            {
                public long Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public IEnumerable<StationViewModel> Stations { get; set; }
            }

            public sealed class StationViewModel
            {
                public long Id { get; set; }
                public string Description { get; set; }
                public IEnumerable<RubricViewModel> Rubrics { get; set; }
            }

            public sealed class RubricViewModel
            {
                public long Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Info { get; set; }
                public IEnumerable<SubRubricViewModel> SubRubrics { get; set; }
            }

            public sealed class SubRubricViewModel
            {
                public long Id { get; set; }
                public int Order { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Info { get; set; }
                public string Type { get; set; }
                public IEnumerable<SubRubricItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
            }

            public sealed class SubRubricItemViewModel
            {
                public long Id { get; set; }
                public int Order { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Info { get; set; }
                public string Type { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be translated to SQL.  So either run the SQL query before the `.Select()`,

```
.ThenInclude(subRubric => subRubric.Items)
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(exam => new Result.ExamViewModel
```

or remove the `Include`s (they don't do anything when you have a custom projection, and thereby change the query)

```
SubRubrics = rubric.SubRubrics.Select((subRubric) => new Result.SubRubricViewModel
{
    Id = subRubric.Id,
    Order = 0, . . .
```

and fill in the `Order` property on the view models afterwards.

Comment: "_or remove the Includes (the don't do anything when you have a custom projection), and change the query_": => oh ok, thanks, that is something I wasn't familiar with. Is it somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: It probably should be doc'd.  But since your result type is not the same as the Entity Type, there would be no way to use the eager-loaded Navigation Properties.

Comment: It works without the Include statements, I thought I had to provide them no matter if I changed it afterwards. I must have misread the docs completely, misinterpreted this then. Thanks for the feedback. Will mark as ok as soon as I can.